# can't debug class reloaded through spring-loaded in Netbeans

Tags: debugging, netbeans, jhipster, spring-loaded

I would like to know if anyone has succeeded in making his debugger stop within a class reloaded through spring-loaded in Netbeans (or another IDE) ?

Thank you very much in advance for your feedback.

PS: JRebel works fine but it's far from free.

Comment: It was designed to behave in Eclipse - although there are no regression tests confirming that so it possibly regressed. Try it out? IIRC the hipster guys were using IntelliJ so it would be interesting to hear from them how debugging behaves in IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer to my own question: I'm able to break in the re-loaded code when using eclipse (STS to be exact) but I still have no luck with Netbeans and IntelliJ...still interested to know if someone managed to make it work on one of those 2 platforms.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour affects IDEA and Netbeans, and has been reported [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-loaded/issues/67#issuecomment-61662418).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25353718/2675154) post gave me the workaround for these two IDEs, but it involves enabling remote debugging.

To do that in IntelliJ you have to create a remote debug configuration, and IntelliJ will give you the JVM argument to add. By default this is:

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
```

Add that argument to your run configuration and start run configuration and remote debug and IntelliJ works like a normal debug.