# Breakpoints does not work after reloading classes with springloaded in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, hotdeploy, spring-loaded

I'm running my java application with an "Application" configuration in Intellij
and I'm using these vm options for using springloaded:
`-javaagent:.../springloaded-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar -noverify`

The class reloading with springloaded works fine.

But the debugger won't stop any more at the breakpoints in the reloaded classes.
Breakpoints in other classes still work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution works:

- start the application in run mode (instead of debug mode) with the remote debug option:
  `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005`
- Start remote debug from intellij.

But perhaps there's a better solution?

Comment: There's an open Github issue on this, but I found this post first and it worked for me. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-loaded/issues/67

Comment: This approach helped me when dealing with Grails development